# Doubt with the Schild's ladder construction

Tags: differential-geometry

I don't understand how the Schild's ladder (for parallel transporting a vector through a geodesic) can be applied for example in a sphere where the tangent vector seems to be out of the manifold (the sphere itself).

From the Wikipedia entry on the Schild's ladder:

[image: Schild's ladder from Wikipedia entry]

We can see that if $\overline{A_0 X_0}$ is the vector and $A_1$ is the point in the curve where we begin the origin of the parallel new vector, the geodesic joining $X_0$ with $A_1$ does not always exist, for instance in an sphere, if $\overline{A_0 X_0}$ is a tangent vector whose ending point (the "arrow") $X_0$ is "out" of the sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say $v$ is the tangent vector at $A_0$ you want to transport. Then $A_0X_0$ is not $v$ itself, but rather a geodesic on the surface such that $v$ is also a tangent to the geodesic at $A$. In particular, $X_0$ lies on the surface of $S$.

To illustrate, here's a mediocre image of Schild's ladder on a cylinder, transporting the red tangent vectors:

[image]

As you can see, the red tangent vectors are tangent to the geodesics $A_iX_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the very helpful drawing. My doubt is solved!

Comment: Your drawing should replace the one in the wikipedia article, it's a lot clearer. The article says it with words (the crucial point being the expontential mapping from v to A0X0) but your drawing nails it.

Answer (score 1):

Schild's ladder is strictly a transport operation of the ordered pair $(A_0, X_0)$ along the tuple $(A_0, A_1, A_2, \ldots)$. The moved couples are $(A_1, X_1)$, $(A_2, X_2)\ldots$ The construction of the point $X_1$ is a 4-step operation:

1. Find the geodesic between $X_0$ and $A_1$
2. Measure it and find the mid-point $P_1$
3. Find the geodesic between $X_0$ and $P_1$
4. Measure it and extend it of to twice its length; you have $X_1$ now

And the operation is repeated for the points $X_2, X_3, \ldots$

The construction of each couple of geodesics can be exact, and it is at least a second order process.

Now the identification of couples $(A_0, X_0)$, $(A_0, A_1)$, $(A_1, X_1)$ with vectors $V_0$, $U_0$, $V_1$ is only possible at first order. Considering that $V_0$ and $V_1$ are the tangent vectors of the geodesics $A_0X_0$, $A_1 X_1$ at $A_0$ and $A_1$ is not particularly relevant.

Here a picture: [Schild's ladder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNQSE.png) Bold solid lines: the geodesics ; dashed lines: the couples, corresponding to vectors, to the first order of approximation.